# Tahitian Lime tree leaves eaten?

Tags: plant-health, pest-control, citrus, pest-damage

I got this Tahitian Dwarf Lime tree not long ago and I was surprised to find a few of the leaves being bitten. I'm not sure what to do to stop/prevent this from reocurring. Any advice?

[image]